# Scatterplot with R from text file with log scale

Tags: r, plot, scatter-plot

I have data saved in a text file with couple thousands line. Each line only has one value. Like this

```
52312
2
3
4
5
7
9
4
5
3
```

The first value is always roughly 10.000 times bigger than all the other values.

I can read in the data with `data<-read.table("data.txt")`

When I just use `plot(data)` all the data have the same y-value, resulting in a line, where the x values just represent the values given from the data.

What I want, however, is that the x-value represents the linenumber and y-value the actual data. So for the above example my values would be `(1,52312)`, `(2,2)`, `(3,3)`, `(4,4)`, `(5,5)`, `(6,7)`, `(7,9)`, `(8,4)`, `(9,5)`, `(10,3)`.

Also, since the first value is way higher than all the other values, I'd like to use a log scale for the y-axis.

Sorry, very new to `R`.

Comment: being new to R I do agree the start is difficult. But did you try from your end finding/reading about functions? The solution is very easy but you would learn nothing if we just post the answer

Comment: I would gladly read it up, but not sure what to search for to be honest. I started here, but didn't really help: http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/scatterplot.html

Comment: @joel.wilson So if you could point me to the correct documentation or some helpful keywords, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set.seed(1000)    
df = data.frame(a=c(9999999,sample(2:78,77,replace = F)))
plot(x=1:nrow(df), y=log(df$a))
```

i) set.seed(1000) helps you reproduce the same random numbers from sample() each time you run this code. It makes code reproducible.

ii) type ?sample in R console for documentation.
iii) since you wanted the x-axis to be linenumber - I create it using ":" operator. 1:3 = 1,2,3. Similarily I created a "id" index using 1:nrow(df) which will create based on the dimension of your data.

iv) for log ,just use it simple :). read more about ?plot and its parameters

Comment: Cool! It almost works. I currently have `df = data.frame(a=c(data$V1))` and then `plot(x=1:nrow(df), y=log(df$a), log="y")`, but then I get the warning `Warning message:
In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :
  11978 y values <= 0 omitted from logarithmic plot` I suppose because most of my values are actually floating points, ranging from `0.0001`–`0.003`. How would you suggest that I set the range of my values?

Comment: This is bcoz some of your y-values are negative. So log returns warnings. You can ignore that if you want

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df
    x     y
1   1 52312
2   2     2
3   3     3
4   4     4
5   5     5
6   6     7
7   7     9
8   8     4
9   9     5
10 10     3

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point(size=2) + scale_y_log10()
```

[image]

Comment: That's beautiful. I haven't understood how to create the `data.frame` though. My data would be your y-values. How do I generate the `df` from that?